Mismatched IDs Between Two tables with relation using QField and QGIS
I am setting up my qgis qfield survey app. I have a shape file of metadata.shp that has a field “id” and another non geometric table log.dbf that has a field “fk_id”. They are in relation based on id and fk_id where log table being the referencing layer. I included relation in the metadata layers attribute form so that i can directly insert multiple data into the log table. I setup the default values as well to go incrementing. However, it perfectly works in the qgis attribute forms. But in qfield, it increments by two steps for each point.
Lets see an instance where my existing maximum metadata id is 25.
I use the same attribute form for both tables via relation, at first I can see the 26 in the id field before clicking ok. after clicking ok, the log table gets its fk_id records as 26, but the metadata.shp id becomes 27. the next point is log fk_id is 28, and metadata id is 29.
this happens only in qfield, it works perfectly in qgis forms

I had ticked the Apply default value on update for the id field in metadata.shp and it made the values to increment by 2.
